# when can we pass value directly to 'state' redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs

can we pass the value directly to the state in redux reducer like

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_USER':
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

here i added action payload value to state , i was wondering is it safe to do that ?
if i only return `acion.payload` , i would get a error that says

> state.users.find is not a function
> here is `mapStateToProps` function

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return { user: state.users.find(user => user.id === ownProps.userId) };
}
```

what is the best practice?
if you need more information please let me know

Comment: `state` is an array in your first snippet, so it's unclear what you expect `state.users` to be.

Comment: i've tried `state = {users:[ ] }` but it went wrong . how can i fix this issue?

Comment: Please post the whole code for this example. How is your redux state initialised, and what payload is dispatched with `FETCH_USER`? And apart from the code that does this, what did you *mean* to do?

Answer (score 0):

You should define an initial state in your reducer like:

```
const initialState = {
   users: []
}
```

Then initialize the state with the initial state, and update it with your payload:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_USER':
      return {...state, users: action.payload};
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: i got the same result if i change `return {...state, users: action.payload};` to   ` return action.payload;` i'm trying to find a way that doesn't pass the value directly to state , i think it passes the value either , how can i do that?

Comment: This is the way of using redux. What do you mean by passing the value? What kind of data are you receiving in your action.payload? What is the real problem? You're getting the error because state.users it's not defined, with this approach it is defined so you should not get any error.